# Qual a diferença entre o MDBootstrap e o Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

atualmente uso Bootstrap mas dando uma pesquisada, descobri o MDB. Vi que ele contém mais contato com linguagem de programação do que o Bootstrap, e queria saber a diferença desses dois. Afinal, qual seria o melhor para usar? Depende do gosto?

https://getbootstrap.com.br/

https://mdbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felipe primeiro tenha em mente que o MDB é pago, ele não é 100% free, já o Bootstrap original é free. Na verde eu não entendo muito de licenciamento, e nem sei se seria permitido alguém cobrar por algo que usa Bootstrap

> Code licensed MIT, docs CC BY 3.0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, o fato do MDB ser `componentizado` não quer dizer que só ele existe, vc pode encontrar facilmente versões `componentizadas` do Bootstrap para os *frameworks* mais populares!

- **Angula**: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
- **React**: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap
- **Vue**: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue

Ou ainda se vc quer um Bootstrap tematizado para fica com o aspecto do Material Design (https://material.io/develop/web/) vc tem uma opção free aqui https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

O MDB facilita a sua vida pq já está tudo empacotado, tem templates pagos e suporte pago, mas se vc não quer pagar por isso existem outras opções para vc "expandir" as classes do Bootstrap para outros "temas" como é o caso do Material Design. *Bootstrap também vende templates pagos no site oficial https://themes.getbootstrap.com/, mas não tem opção de suporte nem pagando...*

Acho que não tem nada a ver com gosto. Na verdade nem entendi o que vc quis dizer com isso... Todo mundo é livre para customizar o Bootstrap como bem entender. Já vender essa modificação no mercado, ou cobrar por alguma coisa que tem como base o Bootstrap eu não sei exatamente dizer se é permitido dentro dos termos de licença do código.

Se vc quir um layout com cara de Material Design vc mesmo pode customizar o BS para isso, ou usar alguma das opções que citei caso precise de algo `componentizado` para algum *framework* JavaScrip.